# Adding a space after 4 chars in an input

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I thought that this would add a space after each 4 chars, but instead, after the fourth digit the input is set to ''. Why?

```
keyUp: function(e) {
    if (e.target.value.length === 4) {
      var value = e.target.value + ' ';
      e.target.value = value;
    }
    else if (e.target.value.length === 9) {
      e.target.value += ' ';
    }
    else if (e.target.value.length === 14) {
      e.target.value += ' ';
    }
  },
```

Comment: Your code works as intended for me. Could it be some ember thing? As a sidenote: it's annoying when trying to use the backspace when you mistyped a digit, since you can't go back beyond the last space since it'll get added again all the time. So best to add a check if the key pressed is the backspace.

Comment: I think it works: http://jsfiddle.net/ct3g5oc4/

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean, funny it isn't working in Ember. Well thanks anyway :)